# My picturebox image is not saving to dropbox folder using Api

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, api, dropbox

here is my Code :

```
static string token = "<REDACTED>";


async Task Upload()
{        
    using (var dbx = new DropboxClient(token))

    {
        //C: \Users\home\Downloads\abba.JPG

        //string file = @"C:\Users\home\Downloads\FazalNEwTEst.JPG";
        string folder = "";
        string filename = "EziTest-2-jun-2020.JPG";
        string url = pictureBox1.Image.ToString();

        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(pictureBox1.Image, typeof(byte[]));
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        var mem = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(base64String));
        //using ()
        //{
            var updated = dbx.Files.UploadAsync(folder + "/" + filename, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: mem);
            updated.Wait();
            var tx = dbx.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(folder + "/" + filename);
            tx.Wait();
            url = tx.Result.Url;

        //}

        //Console.Write(url)
    }
}
```

The button Click code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    var awt = Task.Run((Func<Task>)this.Upload);
    awt.Wait();
}
```

When i click on image picturebox image should be saved to dropbox folder using token of Api. But actually it gives me error which is

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\visual studio projects\Windows form Application tutorials\Dropbox Api Demo\Dropbox Api Demo\bin\Debug\iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC\xhBQAAA1FJREFUeF7t2ttLVFEcxXH\qKjogmWWRplaSEkWQUIPQkkQShTZlbySZqKZEZTVQzcIIgiKUMtSpEC6IFbmZRzHchwVEkd27OEneNyBOM1h1tlnfWE9neM87A8y4xlTGGOMMWZx11rvKs79yXEvn775YEu72tncw7kwfbYrBtE\uKqxj3Nh+mwJAjSCgI0gYCMI2AgCNoKAjSBgIwjYCAI2goAtLhA+y3JvcT3L4tyfHPfylVbeUP0\RxRzJ322+ozluJePIO5GELAIAhZBwCIIWAQBiyBgEQQsgoBFELAIAhZBwCIIWAQBiyBgEQQsz4J0dHarx0+fJ3RDIwF59eTlWZDikrNq9aashO7FqzZ59eRFkEUjyH+UaJC1adlqYHBIXj15eRbkZFm52pKVH9f04S8FOVdeK6+c3DwLEm+h8V9qY8YeB8b69FyIN3Sd70Au1zQ4MPQqaxvlavLzFUggOKY2bN3twNC\LWOhcbkj+fkK5FLVVQeGXn3TLbmKkW9AAqPB2HvFYoy0HXtVeDIid2DkG5ALFXUODL2mm61yFSdfgAwOB9S69BwHRmpmnpoIT8odOPkCpOJKowNDr6a+Wa5iZT1IZGpapW7Pc2Do35bRYEjuwMp6kDv3Hzkw9E6fr5KreFkNMj8\r3LyCw2Qj72f5Q68rAZ5+brDwCgoPCZXMbMa5MjRUgNEfxGFnLUgX\v6DQz9mGRqekbuwMxakOq66wYI8pv5QlaCRKNRlZl7wADp7OqRO3CzEqTtzXsDIyOnIPapCz0rQc5crDZA9LMsL2QdyNxcNPY17VKQ9rddcgd21oG86\5gYOhHJ7Ozs3IHdtaB

Comment: From error message it looks like you are saving content as a file name. Moreover content looks like encoding, you are missing conversion from that encoding to `byte[]` somewhere.

Comment: Sir when i give path of image means at url when i give directory path of image then its work . there is small error which is not recognizing by me...Anyone???

Comment: These things: `string url = pictureBox1.Image.ToString();` and `var mem = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(base64String));` have no meaning or sense. The upload thing tries to pass a file name using a relative path then trying to also use an non-existent byte array. You **really** need to read the documentation again and debug your code.

Comment: After removing the string " url" and" memory stream" it still giving me error of file path!!!!??

Comment: I redacted the access token from your post, but you really should [revoke](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Auth_Routes_AuthUserRoutes_TokenRevokeAsync.htm) it since you shared it publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the lines

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(pictureBox1.Image, typeof(byte[]));
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
var mem = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(base64String));
```

To

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(pictureBox1.Image, typeof(byte[]));
var mem = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

You don't need to convert the `byte` array to a base64 `string`. It is the code `File.ReadAllBytes(base64String)` that tries to read the file with the gibberish name from disk